# Prim , Kruskal or Dijkstra

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

I've a lot of doubts on these three algorithm , I can't understand when I've to use one or the other in the exercise , because the problem of minimum spanning tree and shortest path are very similar . Someone can explain me the difference and give me some advice on how I can solve the exercise? Thank you so much.

Comment: Consider $A,B,C$ with $d(A,B) = 2, d(B,C) = 2, d(A,C) = 3$. The minimum spanning tree is $(AB,BC)$ but the shortest path in the original graph between $A$ and $C$ is $3$, whereas it becomes $4$ in the minimum spanning tree. Kruskal and Dijkstra's algorithms just don't have the same purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I start in Washington DC and I want to travel to Roanoke. What is the shortest way to get there? This is a case where you would want to use Dijkstra's Algorithm.

I live in Roanoke. We got a large snowstorm and have to plow the roads. What roads do we plow to enable everyone to travel to any location in the city? Here, we aren't concerned with a single shortest path, but the overall minimum cost in plowing roads to enable a path from every two points in the city. This is the minimum spanning tree problem. Notice that a tree is a minimally connected graph (in terms of the number of edges). The MST minimizes the cost of the tree, based on the edge weights.

Answer (score 1):

Prim and Kruskal are for spanning trees, and they are most commonly used when the problem is to connect *all* vertices, in the cheapest way possible.

For Example, designing routes between cities.

Dijkstra, is for finding the cheapest route between two vertices.

For Example, GPS navigation.